# Simplify bash script with variables

Tags: bash, variables

I am currently trying to simplify a script. Instead of manually entering a host name for each command, I'd like to be able to use variables? arrays? of some sort. Was wondering if you can help.

Example:

```
hostname1=192.168.1.1
hostname2=192.168.1.2

echo "What would you like to do?"
echo "(1)Ping Hosts"
echo "(2)mkdir /tmp/test"
echo "(3)write to test.txt"
read num_variable

if num_variable = 1
then
ping hostname1
ping hostname2

if num_variable = 2 
ssh -n hostname1 "mkdir /tmp/test"
ssh -n hostname2 "mkdir /tmp/test"

if num_variable = 3
ssh -n hostname1 "echo 'hello' > /tmp/test/test.txt"
ssh -n hostname2 "echo 'hello' > /tmp/test/test.txt"
```

**"Is there an easier way to write this?"**

Example:

```
Hosts=hostname1,hostname2
```

Commands here?

I'd hate to have 20,000 lines when all i could do is list the hostnames on top and for each num variable execute all of the commands below for the hosts listed in that particular section.

Comment: Note that you want `if [ $num_variable = 1 ]`, etc

Comment: Yeah.. it was simplified version. :) Thank you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array:

```
hosts=(hostname1 hostname2 hostname3)
```

You can split it to multiple lines:

```
hosts=(
        hostname1 
        hostname2 
        hostname3
      )
```

Iterate over the elements:

```
for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
    echo "$host"
done
```

Access a particular host:

```
echo "${hosts[2]}"
```

Use the `select` command to create a menu:

```
PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    echo "Opt: $opt, Reply: $REPLY"
    case $opt in
        "Option 1")
            echo "you chose choice 1"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 2"
            ;;
        "Option 2")
            echo "you chose choice 3"
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: All of you helped tremendously. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Bash does have arrays that you can iterate over.

```
hosts=(hostname1
       hostname2
       hostname3)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
   ssh -n "$host" "echo 'hello' > /tmp/test/test.txt" 
done
```

Comment: All of you helped tremendously. Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help. The best way to say "thanks" is by upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and a `case` statement.

An example of a `for` loop would be:

```
nodes="192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3"
for node in $nodes
do
    echo $node
done
```

An example of a `case` statement would be

```
case "$num_variable" in
    "1" ) echo "1";;
    "2" ) echo "2";;
    "3" ) echo "3";;
esac
```

Combining the two is an exercise for  you :-)

A good reference to `bash` is the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf).

Comment: This would be a good way if the code was meant to be portable to other POSIX shells.

Comment: @jordanm Hey, what is wrong with portable code? I thought that was supposed to be a good thing...

Comment: Restricting yourself to POSIX-only features can result in ugly and more difficult to maintain code. Most of us inside of a linux bubble really don't care if our code will run on a *bsd machine, and would rather make use of the extended features.